# spring-data-elasticsearch + elasticsearch REST API

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

there!

I'm very new in elasticsearch, but it's looks very nice and I like it

I have simple domain and spring elasticsearch repository

```java
@Document(indexName = "user", type = "customer")
public class CustomerUser {
  @Id
  String id;
  String username, name;
}

public interface CustomerUserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<CustomerUser, String> {}
```

What I'm expecting is to have some kind of data/API synchronization between spring-data-elasticsearch and elasticsearch REST API, so different apps can use both - my custom backend API and elasticsearch API

I've created few items using my custom REST API and spring-data repository:

```sh
http post :8001 name=Max1 username=daggerok1
http get :8001/users

{
    "_embedded": {
        "userList": [
            {
                "id": "AV-DhBJaR-bqR3BWmtKy",
                "name": "Max1",
                "username": "daggerok1"
            }
        ]
    }...
```

but I cannot query/access them using elasticsearch REST API by /user/customer/$ID

```sh
http -a elastic:changeme :9200/user/customer/AV-DhBJaR-bqR3BWmtKy
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Can anybody point me what I'm doing wrong and how I should store spring-data items or configure my spring-boot app for accessing them later using elasticsearch REST API too? Just like so:

```sh
echo '{"username":"daggerok","name":"Max"}'|http -a elastic:changeme :9200/user/customer
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: /user/customer/AV-DkFD1Y98z-Zp73zW8

{
    "_id": "AV-DkFD1Y98z-Zp73zW8",
    "_index": "user",
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 1,
        "total": 2
    },
    "_type": "customer",
    "_version": 1,
    "created": true,
    "result": "created"
}

$ http -a elastic:changeme :9200/user/customer/AV-DkFD1Y98z-Zp73zW8
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
    "_id": "AV-DkFD1Y98z-Zp73zW8",
    "_index": "user",
    "_source": {
        "name": "Max",
        "username": "daggerok"
    },
    "_type": "customer",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true
}
```

I've also tried on application bootstrap explicitly create index and mapping, but it's doesn't helped:

```java
elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(CustomerUser.class);
elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(CustomerUser.class);
elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(CustomerUser.class);
```

Thanks!

---

Regards,
Maksim